# Grails MySQL database reset on each restart of the application

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am new in Grails. I am facing a very irritating problem. **Why my grails app reset all the tables data on each restart of the application.** For example I have Post domain class. When I create some data it is save in my Database. But When I again restart my application. All rows are reset. I don't know why it happened.

Check my DataSource.groovy ...

```
dataSource {
  pooled = true
  driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
}
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = true
  cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
   development {
      dataSource {
          dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
          url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
          username = "root"
          password = ""
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
       }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
    }
   }
  }
```

I am testing my application on localhost:8080 (development environment). Please clarify me this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...

I change my DataSource.groovy from this

```
development {
  dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
      username = "root"
      password = ""
    }
}
```

to

```
 development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
    }
}
```

It works for me... :)

Comment: Even in case of dbCreate = "update", your data base should not reset

Comment: Just an advice: remember that if you change any of your domain classes, Grails problably will show an error as you have to delete and create that table again. In this case, change it to `dbCreate = "create"` temporally...

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code in my DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
  pooled = true
  driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
}
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = true
  cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
      dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/blog?autoReconnect=truejdbcCompliantTruncation=false"
        username = "root"
        password = ""
      }
   }
}
```